# Percentile_disc() for a non round values

Tags: oracle, percentile

I'm trying to find a solution for this with no luck.

In my query, im selecting the `count(*)` and the `percentile_disc(.9)` to find the 90th position of this.
The case is, when the count is 29, the 90th percentile is closer to the number 26 than 27 but still returning the 27th object.

There is any way to say, if 5 < Nth <10 reduce by one the result?

Table for reference

```
ID    Count    90th
-------------------
1     50       45
2     40       36
3     27       25     <-- Should be 24
4      9        9     <-- Should be  8
```

90% of 9 is 0.9, it should delete 1 and resulting 8.

---Till here is my understanding of Nth percentile---

Now what I have:

My table have a los of entries (+ 100k at day) so I want to run this query on daily basis.

```
Service_id   start_time      end_time
-------------------------------------
Service1    1499025651614    1499025651648
Service2    1499025655145    1499025655434
Service3    1499025656029    1499025656112
Service2    1499025658755    1499025659135
Service3    1499025726862    1499025728346
Service1    1499025748782    1499025750032
Service3    1499025749277    1499025749900
Service3    1499025757681    1499025758517
Service2    1499025775000    1499025775101
Service1    1499025785556    1499025785633
...
```

I have a query to select the min, max and avg for every service

```
 select mt.SERVICE_ID as SERVICE_ID,
           count(*) as COUNT,
           round(avg((mt.end_time - mt.start_time) / 1000), 2) as Avg,
           round(min((mt.end_time - mt.start_time) / 1000), 2) AS Min,
           round(max((mt.end_time - mt.start_time) / 1000), 2) AS Max
      from myTable mt
     group by mt.service_id
```

And I want to incorporate the 90th percentile discused before using a join.

```
select service_id, round(percentile_disc(.90) within group(order by elapsed), 2) as perc
from (select mt.service_id, ((mt.end_time - mt.start_time) / 1000) as elapsed
      from myTable mt)
group by service_id
```

The issue comes when the count is (lets say) 9, in this case, the `MAX` and the `Perc` is the same (due the percentile is not removing anything) but I need in this particular case, to remove the last one, giving me as result the timming in the position 8th.

There is any way to remove one more position in this case?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including the DDL statements for your tables, DML statements for example data which illustrates your problem and your expected output (with a detailed description of the logic of why that output is expected). Currently, the text description in your question does not match the "Table for reference" and neither matches your query so it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MT0 more data added, hope is enough for clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PERCENTILE_DISC()` does not quite do what you think it does.

[**Oracle Documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions111.htm):

> **Purpose**
>
> PERCENTILE_DISC is an inverse distribution function that assumes a discrete distribution model. It takes a percentile value and a sort specification and returns an element from the set. Nulls are ignored in the calculation.
>
> ...
>
> For a given percentile value `P`, `PERCENTILE_DISC` sorts the values of the expression in the ORDER BY clause and returns the value with the smallest `CUME_DIST` value (with respect to the same sort specification) that is greater than or equal to `P`.
>
> **Analytic Example**
>
> The following example calculates the median discrete percentile of the salary of each employee in the sample table hr.employees:
>
> ```
> SELECT last_name, salary, department_id,
>    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY salary DESC)
>       OVER (PARTITION BY department_id) "Percentile_Disc",
>    CUME_DIST() OVER (PARTITION BY department_id 
>       ORDER BY salary DESC) "Cume_Dist"
> FROM employees where department_id in (30, 60);
>
> LAST_NAME         SALARY DEPARTMENT_ID Percentile_Disc  Cume_Dist
> ------------- ---------- ------------- --------------- ----------
> Raphaely           11000            30            2900 .166666667
> Khoo                3100            30            2900 .333333333
> Baida               2900            30            2900         .5
> Tobias              2800            30            2900 .666666667
> Himuro              2600            30            2900 .833333333
> Colmenares          2500            30            2900          1
> Hunold              9000            60            4800         .2
> Ernst               6000            60            4800         .4
> Austin              4800            60            4800         .8
> Pataballa           4800            60            4800         .8
> Lorentz             4200            60            4800          1
> ```
>
> The median value for Department 30 is 2900, which is the value whose
>   corresponding percentile (Cume_Dist) is the smallest value greater
>   than or equal to 0.5. The median value for Department 60 is 4800,
>   which is the value whose corresponding percentile is the smallest
>   value greater than or equal to 0.5.

In the example they gave in the documentation, if the percentile was set to `0.9` (rather than `0.5`) then you can see that the `CUME_DIST` goes from `0.8` to `1` (for department 60) so `PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) ...` would give `4200` since this is the value with the smallest `CUME_DIST` greater than or equal to `0.9`. To get the penultimate value you would need a percentile of `0.8` in that case.

> The issue comes when the count is (lets say) 9, in this case, the MAX and the Perc is the same (due the percentile is not removing anything) but I need in this particular case, to remove the last one, giving me as result the timing in the position 8th.

For 9 items, the `CUME_DIST` values for each row will be:

```
ROW_NUMBER CUME_DIST
---------- ---------
         1      .111
         2      .222
         3      .333
         4      .444
         5      .556
         6      .667
         7      .778
         8      .889
         9     1.000
```

If you use `PERCENTILE_DISC( 0.9 )` then it will look for the value which has the lowest `CUME_DIST` greater than or equal to that value - there is only a single value `1.000` which is also the maximum value.

If you want a different value then you need to use a lower percentile.

**Update**:

You can try something like this:

```
select service_id, 
       elapsed as perc
from (
  select service_id,
         (end_time - start_time) / 1000 as elapsed,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY service_id ORDER BY (end_time - start_time) )
           AS rn,
         COUNT() OVER ( PARTITION BY service_id ) AS ct
  from   myTable
)
WHERE rn = ROUND( 0.9 * ct );
```

Change the last line to use `ROUND`, `FLOOR` or `CEIL` as appropriate to your business logic. If I have determined the logic correctly, `CEIL` will give the same answer as using `PERCENTILE_DISC`.

> What I need is the count is 7, remove the last record and return the 6th value (90% of 7 is 0.7 , round to 1), is the count is 21, remove the last 2 records and return the 19th position-value (90% of 21 is 2.1 round to 2) and so on.

Using `rn = ROUND( 0.9 * ct )`:

- If the count is 7 then `0.9 * 7 = 6.3` so `ROUND( 6.3 )` will give the 6th row
- If the count is 21 then `0.9 * 21 = 18.9` so `ROUND( 18.9 )` will give the 19th row
- If the count is 3 then `0.9 * 3 = 2.7` so `ROUND( 2.7 )` will give the 3rd row (the maximum value).

It is unclear what you expect to be returned for small sets - if you never want the maximum row (except when there is only one row) then something like:

```
WHERE rn = GREATEST( 1, LEAST( ct - 1, ROUND( 0.9 * ct ) ) )
```

Comment: So, in this case, what I should need to use?

Comment: If there are 9 rows in your group and you want the 8th value then use `8/9 = 0.888...` (or any value greater than `7/9` and less than or equal to `8/9`).

Comment: And there is any way to automate this? In the DB there is more than 150 different Services, some is called 2 times, some is called +2000 times. What I need is the count is 7, remove the last record and return the 6th value (90% of 7 is 0.7 , round to 1), is the count is 21, remove the last 2 records and return the 19th position-value (90% of 21 is 2.1 round to 2) and so on. Thanks for your time

Comment: @AndresMtnez Updated

Comment: This looks very well, I'll put in work and I'll come back to you.
Thanks @MT0

Comment: I can confirm that this last update work as expected.  Thanks very much!!  You've finished with more than a week of suffering for me.